# typescript conditional types: inference works but the compiler rejects the implementation

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I've used typescript's conditional types with great success, but often I find that while I can express the type signatures, in the implementation of the functions I must use `any` even though I know the implementation is correct.

Example, this definition:

```
type ExportType<InputType extends string|undefined> =
    string extends InputType ? undefined : ()=>void;

function convert<InputType extends string|undefined>(input: InputType): ExportType<InputType>;
```

(I know I could use overloads, but my real issue is more complex and overloads wouldn't be realistic for the real issue)

In effect the signature is saying "if the parameter is `string`, I'll return `()=>void`, if it's `undefined`, I'll return `undefined`.

And this works great. Playing with `convert("x")` and `convert(undefined)` shows that typescript agrees with this definition.

However when actually trying to implement this function:

```
type ExportType<InputType extends string|undefined> =
    string extends InputType ? undefined : ()=>void;

function convert<InputType extends string|undefined>(input: InputType): ExportType<InputType> {
    if (input) {
        return ()=>{console.log("OK");};
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

This does not compile. Typescript says:

```
error TS2322: Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'ExportType<InputType>'.

         return ()=>{console.log("OK");};
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

But that line is in `if (input)`, therefore at this point we know that the input is not `undefined`, so it must be `string`, and therefore we must return `() => void`... But it seems the compiler is just not smart enough to see that.

Changing that line to:

```
    return <any>(()=>{console.log("OK");});
```

Makes it work, but it's disappointing...

So is there a way to write a fully type-safe and checked implementation of this signature that typescript lets us express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will not allow you to assign a value to an unresolved conditional type (ie one that still contains free type parameters). You can use a cast as you discovered or you can use a separate implementation signature:

```
type ExportType<InputType extends string|undefined> =
    string extends InputType ? undefined : ()=>void;

function convert<InputType extends string|undefined>(input: InputType): ExportType<InputType> 
function convert(input: string|undefined): undefined | (()=>void) {
    if (input) {
        return ()=>{console.log("OK");};
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's really disappointing.. I get the feeling the advanced language features are only tuned for wrapping JS libraries (so, `.d.ts` operation mode) and that the implementations themselves are not really a focus :-( -- do you think that's a temporary situation, or is it unlikely to change?

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery I don't think that's really fair... The advanced features are usable in implementations.. just not this particular case. In general typescript does not allow assigning values to generic types, and conditional types are a step further removed even from that. I would agree with you they invest more in getting the call site of such generic functions to work better then the implementation. Generally this type of function is written once and used multiple times, so it makes sense to invest less in getting all the types to work in the implementation.

Comment: I think the issue I hit is in fact https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735