# How do I get conditional types to work in this example from the official Typescript documentation?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I was looking at the typescript docs and landed on [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) on conditional types.

I was trying to implement the `createLabel` function in this way:

```js
interface IdLabel {
  id: number /* some fields */;
}
interface NameLabel {
  name: string /* other fields */;
}
type NameOrId<T extends number | string> = T extends number
  ? IdLabel
  : NameLabel;

function createLabel<T extends number | string>(nameOrId: T): NameOrId<T>  {
  const label: NameOrId<T> = (typeof nameOrId === 'number') ? { id: nameOrId }: { name: nameOrId} ;
  return label;
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error on the `label` creation

```js
Type '{ id: number; } | { name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.
  Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'NameOrId<T>'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a current limitation with TS and the relevant GitHub issue is [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912); for now you will need type assertions or overloads to work around it, as shown in the existing answers to the question. Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer (or maybe one of the existing answers should be edited). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It's clearer now. Thanks for the link to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code is that TypeScript is unable to infer the correct type of the returned value from the createLabel function. To fix this, you can use a type assertion to explicitly tell TypeScript what the type of the returned value should be.

Here's the corrected code:

```
interface IdLabel {
  id: number /* some fields */;
}

interface NameLabel {
  name: string /* other fields */;
}

type NameOrId<T extends number | string> = T extends number
  ? IdLabel
  : NameLabel;

function createLabel<T extends number | string>(nameOrId: T): NameOrId<T> {
  return typeof nameOrId === "number"
    ? { id: nameOrId } as NameOrId<T>
    : { name: nameOrId } as NameOrId<T>;
}

const Name = createLabel("5"); // Type is NameLabel
const Id = createLabel(5); // Type is IdLabel
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMAycBGEA2yA3gFDLLDoBcyIArgLZ5TID0AVMgM4D2DKMYAXRdk7VgG4SAXxIlQkWIhQA5OP2x5CpciHUQaXMFFABzNpx5gAFtGSDho8VNkkwATwAOq-QHkoGAA8ACrIEAAekCAitIzMyAA%203MZmAHzIALzIoRFRMfRM0GTIAPxoWLgExTRqGpX4UiQwdCAIYMA8IMgIUBBwkJoEIWGRENGiBfFJRiYgpqkAFHr8-hg0wQCUNX4B6CHpOsi9YHRQXR7ePDC0OxiZGVkARJPQj8XkZUQU1Dcru8jSZBwUS1CCrPbBVLvZA0L7LAy-MH-QHA5Cg8H7FxyBCdIxo-SZbq9foQQb4BaPACsjw2EjYrGyXhQwBB%20jJJBxIDxdyyPT6A3qC0ptPpjO8FFEGDJQA)

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand this. Even casting the two possible return values to `IdLabel` and `NameLabel` instead of `NameOrId<T>` is not valid. Why is this a problem for typescript?

Comment: I believe @ScreamZ misuses the terms here a bit. In the expression `const label = ...`, TS is able to *infer* the type of `label`, and it's a good inference (it's basically a union). But, as Titian explained in the answer I linked, this type is just not assignable to an unresolved conditional type. Why is it like this? I don't know. So, type assertion (basically telling TS to shut up) works. But also, a separate implementation with union types works, and looks like in this case TS is only checking that implementation signature and overloaded signature are compatible (and they indeed are!)

Comment: @jcalz could maybe gives more intel about it

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question closely relates to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53071886/13942930)

Titian's answer there explains all the details, so for completeness, I will just provide a [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBMAycBGEA2yA3gFDLLDoBcyIArgLZ5TID0AVMgM4D2DKMYAXRdk7VgG4SAXxKhIsRCgBycftjyFS5EGog0uYKKADmbTjzAALaMkHDR4qbLABPAA4q9AeSgYAPAAqyBAAHpAgIrSMzMgAPtxGpgB8yAC8yMFhEVH0TNBkyAD8aFi4BIU0qurl+FIkbp6ZEIYAjOnI1RC+AXnMyfUwdCAIYMA8IMgIUBBwkBoEQSHhEJGifbYJhsYgJskAFLr8PdSZAJRVPn7oQQMkJKysyADqKADuwPiEdFwocNwQdxwKBzFDABjufAQfjgObjSZcYAmXRgOgzEhDEZjCZTGaghb4Q5XDA0DYsLZJXYXUoE+KdPS07RTCaGZD4WodfaNCA8GC0YnodJpDIAcjJIrOxWIFFOR2612Q0hoRH5-FJAukyCk5BmqKgk3Zmmc90eyG5FFEGFpNnRCBZYBltIy01m81q+1aACYAMxneqm83AURda3QCAkO0gVlyp2410QAn7ABEACkeFZJgARHgQJN+khAA) which works for your example. I used a separate implementation signature with just union types, but that's not the only way to do it.